# Moving Same files from different folders using shell script on AIX 5.4

Tags: shell, shell-script

There are two folders named Folder1 and Folder2.
Folder1 has files with name:For example
S-080001-0-0.xml with its corresponding same files in Folder2 named S-080001-0-0.xml

The change in Folder2 is that,for same file in Folder1 which is S-080001-0-0.xml,Folder 2 contains multiple files with different value after hyphen,like -080001-0-0.xml,-080001-0-1.xml,-080001-0-2.xml,-080001-0-3.xml.
My challenge is to move all the files of same name from these two folders.

Comment: Please explain. Do you want to add `Folder1/S-080001-0-0.xml` after, e.g., `Folder2/S-080001-0-5.xml` as `Folder2/S-080001-0-6-xml`? Combine them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare based on filename then you can use below :

```
find folder1/ folder2/ -type f -printf %f"\n" | sort |  uniq -c | \
awk '( $1 >= 2 ) {print "mv -vf folder1/"$2,"other_dir/","&&","mv -vf folder2/"$2,"other_dir/"}'
```

it will just print command on terminal , it will not execute that , if you see output is proper then just append `| sh` at the last then it will execute that command